# Excel macro for data reformatting

Tags: excel, vba

I need to reformat a 33500 row of data in excel. I am trying to write a macro that would do this for me.

I have put some nested loop to solve the issue

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim K As Integer
Dim p As Integer
Dim c As Integer

For c = 0 To 10

    For n = 5 To 10

        K = 14 + 7 * (n - 5)

        For i = 0 To 7
            m = 14 + 8 * c
            ActiveSheet.Cells(m + i, n).Select
            Selection.Copy

            ActiveSheet.Cells(K + i, 37).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        Next i

    Next n

Next c
```

I am stuck at how to get this operation done for 32500 rows

Answer (score 0):

Excel's `Integer` has a range of values from -32,768 to 32,767 so formatting 33,500 rows might be a problem.  Assuming that you are happy with how your code works, changing your variable types to `Long` might be a good start.

BTW, you should avoid `SELECTing` cells as it slows down the code and can lead to errors.  You can easily copy and paste between cells using soemthing like

```
Cells(m + i, n).Copy Destination:=Cells(K + i, 37)
```

Comment: Dim i As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim K As Integer
Dim p As Integer

 

  

   For i = 0 To 121
    
  m = 14
   For n = 5 To 35
    
   
    
   
   ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(m + i * 8, n), Cells(m + i * 8 + 7, n)).Copy
   
    
    
   Range("AK" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlValues
    
    
    Next n
    
    
   Next i
   
 
      
    

   
   
   

End Sub
revised the code and working like a charm. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Revised the code according to the comment and now working like a charm. Thank you so much

Dim i As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim K As Integer
Dim p As Integer

For i = 0 To 121

m = 14
   For n = 5 To 35

ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(m + i * 8, n), Cells(m + i * 8 + 7, n)).Copy

Range("AK" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlValues

```
Next n
```

Next i

End Sub